# Why there are two requests when if-modified-since is used and the resource cached needs to be update?

Tags: http

I am having a strange behavior in Epiphany that does not happens with Google chrome.

This is the request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:1026
Accept: text/html,...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 22 May 2015 08:58:02 GMT
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

This is my response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 25 May 2015 07:11:43 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Mon, 25 May 2015 07:11:09 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 134

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

After it I get another request, this time without the `if-modified-since` header.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:1026
Accept: text/html,...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 ...
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Why do I get the second request after sending the resource in response to the first request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bug.
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745067

It seems that Safari has a similar issue.